# Javascript regex replace everything before except contains word

Tags: javascript, regex

I guess it's trivial but I'm struggling with the following situation:

String (HTML delievered as text):

```
text<br>text<br><ul><li>text</li></ul><br>
```

Now I need to replace every `text<br>` with `<div>text</div>`
except if text is inside `<li>/<ul>`.

```
.replace(/(.*?)<br>/g, '<div>$1</div>')
```

This works fine but how to prevent `<ul><li>text</li></ul><br>` from beeing replaced?

Comment: Use an HTML parser, not regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my attempt before asking for a (shorter) regex solution:

```
const dFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
str.textContent.split('<br>').forEach(substr => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  let ul;
  if (!substr) {
    substr = '<br>';
  }
  div.innerHTML = substr;
  ul = div.querySelector('ul');
  if (ul) {
    dFrag.appendChild(ul);
  } else {
    dFrag.appendChild(div);
  }
});
str.innerHTML = '';
str.appendChild(dFrag);
```

Answer (score 0):

["*You can't parse [HTML] with regex. [...] Have you tried using an [HT]ML parser instead?*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)™

(a terser version can be found in the snippet below)

```js
function replaceTextBrWithDiv(html) {
  // Create an element that acts as a parser
  const parser = document.createElement('div');
  parser.innerHTML = html;

  // Modify an array-like when iterating over it may cause some issues.
  // Copy it first.
  const childNodes = [...parser.childNodes];

  // Index-based iterating
  for (let index = 0; index < childNodes.length; index++) {
    const node = childNodes[index];
    const nextNode = childNodes[index + 1];

    if (node instanceof Text && nextNode instanceof HTMLBRElement) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');

      // Remove text node from parser and append it to div
      div.appendChild(node);
      nextNode.replaceWith(div);

      // Skip next node (i.e. <br>)
      index++;
    }
  }

  return parser.innerHTML;
}
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function replaceTextBrWithDiv(html) {
  const parser = document.createElement('div');
  parser.innerHTML = html;

  parser.childNodes.forEach((node, index, nodes) => {
    const nextNode = nodes[index + 1];
    
    if (node instanceof Text && nextNode instanceof HTMLBRElement) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.appendChild(node);
      nextNode.replaceWith(div);
    }
  });
  
  return parser.innerHTML;
}

const content = 'text<br>text<br><ul><li>text</li></ul><br>';

console.log(replaceTextBrWithDiv(content));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for your solution. Actually I've already tested a similiar approach using a container as parser. I'll post it as an answer but it get's out of topic. I should have asked differently: regex for replacing a string that ends with the word <br> and does not start with the word <ul>

Comment: "While arbitrary HTML with only a regex is impossible, it's sometimes appropriate to use them for parsing a limited, known set of HTML."

Comment: Generally, don't. The accepted and most-upvoted answer has its fame for a reason.

Comment: there's no accepted and upvoted answer so far ;-)

Comment: By "*[t]he accepted and most-upvoted answer*" I mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). If you decide to ignore it, good for you then, I guess.

Comment: ah you referred on the other post. Sorry for that one.

Answer (score -1):

If you prefer using regex use */(?!<li.*?>)(?!</li>)(?!<ul.*?>)(?!</ul>)(.*?)
/g*

```
const html = 'text<br>text<br><ul><li>text</li></ul><br>';
const regex = /(?!<li.*?>)(?!<\/li>)(?!<ul.*?>)(?!<\/ul>)(.*?)<br>/g;
const replacedHtml = html.replace(regex, '<div>$1</div>');
console.log(replacedHtml);
```

But it would be better if you switch to HTML parser to easily navigate and modify the structure of the HTML content

Comment: I was expecting comments like use an HTML-Parser. ;-) Since the string is delievered as text and I only need to replace the <br> a regex solution is short and simple. Anyway, your regex doesn't seem to be working:
console.log: <div>text</div><div>text</div><<div>ul><li>text</li></ul></div>